# How to mask a subdirectory name after redirection from domainB.com to domainA.com/subdirectory/?

Tags: .htaccess

Let's say I have a *[www.domainA.com](http://www.domainA.com)* which has a subdirectory, that contains a full page files. In that case, the main file for this page could be found under: *[www.domainA.com/subdirectory/index.html](http://www.domainA.com/subdirectory/index.html)*

I also have *[www.domainB.com](http://www.domainB.com)* - I would like to redirect it to the corresponding content of the *[www.domainA.com/subdirectory/](http://www.domainA.com/subdirectory/)* and also hide the subdirectory name from the user.

### Example 1:

a) user types: *[www.domainB.com](http://www.domainB.com)*

b) it is being redirected to: *[www.domainA.com/subdirectory/index.html](http://www.domainA.com/subdirectory/index.html)*, but the user still sees the URL as *[www.domainB.com/index.html](http://www.domainB.com/index.html)*.

### Example 2:

The same would apply for other files and subdirectories e.g.

a) user types: *[www.domainB.com/pages/about.html](http://www.domainB.com/pages/about.html)*

b) it is being redirected to: *[www.domainA.com/subdirectory/pages/about.html](http://www.domainA.com/subdirectory/pages/about.html)*, but the user still sees the URL as *[www.domainB.com/pages/about.html](http://www.domainB.com/pages/about.html)*.

I've already figured, how to redirect domainB.com to domainA.com/subdirectory/:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainB\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainB\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domainA.com/subdirectory [P]
```

but the subdirectory name still apppears in the URL. For example:
*[www.domainB.com](http://www.domainB.com)* redirects to *[www.domainA.com/subdirectory/index.html](http://www.domainA.com/subdirectory/index.html)*, but it displays as *[www.domainB.com/subdirectory/index.html](http://www.domainB.com/subdirectory/index.html)*.

How to get rid of the displayed subdirectory in the final URL, displayed to the user?

---

**Edit1**:

@CBroe - there is only a single FTP hosting. Currently there are 3 websites files inside it:

a) the files of the main website located directly in the root location (so the location of the index file is: */index.html*)

b) the files of the second website in subdirectory1 (so the location of the index file is: */subdirectory1/index.html*)

c) the files of the third website in subdirectory2 (so the location of the index file is: */subdirectory2/index.html*)

The domainA is the main domain, that points to this server.
The domainB is an additional domain, that I would like to point to the files in the */subdirectory1/*.
The FTP server and both domains come from the same hosting.

My .httaccess configuration, except from the rules I've described, contains only a permanent redirection for one of the websites placed in subdirectory (which has nothing to do with domainB):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainC\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainC\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domainA\.com\/my_subpage\.html" [R=301,L]
```

@MrWhite - the user calls "*domainB.com/[something]*" and should be redirected to "*domainA.com/subdirectory/[something]*" (but still see the "*domainB.com/[something]*" as URL in the browser).

Comment: _“I've already figured, how to redirect ”_ - no, with the `P` flag that is not an actual redirect to begin with, but you are _proxying_ the request. But when doing that, there is no reason why what the address bar shows should change the way you say it does. Is this all of your mod_rewrite configuration? Are the domains hosted on different servers or in different accounts, so that this would be necessary in the first place?

Comment: Also, what about requests of the form `domainB.com/<something>`?